# How to feed classificators with two features

Tags: python, xgboost

I use [this](https://suatatan.com/posts/sklearn_xgboost_tc/) code example with my dataset.

My dataset has 3 columns:

- `username`: a unique alphanumeric (but it can exist on multiple rows)
- `text`: words separated with space (only words, no punctuation or whatever)
- `flag`: 1 or 0

Currently I'm using `x = text`, `y = flag` for the binary classification and works fine.

How can I predict flag using both "user" and "text" ?

I will describe my problem with more detail.

My dataset is like that:

Name Text Label

John,  word1 word2 etc, 0

George, word3 word4 etc, 1

Jenny, word3 word1 etc, 1

The name column have unique data. That means there is one john, one george etc

The text column contains words separated by space (no punctuation or whatever)

The flag column contains a binary flag consist of 1 and 0.

Currently im training my algorithms with X=test and y =Label like this:

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
X= cv.fit_transform(dataset.text)
Y = dataset['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35) 
      
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train
```

)

Now i want to use the Name column AND the text column to feed the X.

Comment: Let `x` be a matrix/table with the two columns `username` and `text` should just work.

Comment: Please add your comment to the post instead of sharing a link or screenshot.

Comment: i have update my question with more details